# RxJS Array of urls to GET requests merged

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm brand new to RxJS and want to do the following (in Angular 2):

1. Request some JSON from the server containing an array of urls
2. Make a request to each of those urls
3. Subscribe to the combined completion of all of those requests

At the moment my method looks like this:

```
    load():void {
        this.http.get(SVG_LIST)
            .map(res => {
                return <Array<string>> res.json().files;
            })
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

What do I chain onto the `map` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the equivalent of `Promise.all`, which is the operator `forkJoin`. You could try something like :

```
load():void {
        this.http.get(SVG_LIST)
            .map(res => {
                return <Array<string>> res.json().files;
            })
            .flatMap(files => Rx.Observable.forkJoin(files.map(makeRequest)))
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

where `files` is an array of urls, `makeRequest` is a function which takes an url and returns an observable or a promise.